# Stored Procedure Safety in Client Enviroment

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am gonna deploy my project by making .dll's file,which gives me my code safety.But when i transfer database to client,all the stored procedure are there,and any one can easily modified my sp's.Tell me how to encrypt or some other sql server hint to avoid the client to modify the sp's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,there is no need to pass your database to your client,you should host your database at some remote server and if there is utter need to pass your database, then use `WITH ENCRYPTION Clause` in your stored procedure,but before using it make sure that you have a backup of each stored procedure.